# Movement in pyjama

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Spyder, Anaconda to code in python 3. I am just getting into the use of pygame and I am unable to move the character. This is the code I am using:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('game')
x = 250
y = 250
width = 20
height = 20
vel = 5
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False   
    pygame.event.pump()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
       x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += vel
    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0),(x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me. Try printing `pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]` in the loop, and tapping `w`to see if the value changes as it may not be registering your input - nothing wrong with the code itself. I am not running through Anaconda, so this may be a problem between Pygame and Anaconda.

BTW, there's no need for pygame.event.pump() as this is used when you check for a quit event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried and I have come to the conclusion that Anaconda doesn't register what keys I press. In fact Anaconda is quite a basic python editor, any suggestions for a new one?